# passing args as reference to pointer with(no) constness gives different addresses

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

```
void f(char  *  & pch) {
    cout << &pch << " " << pch << endl;
}

int main() {
    char *pch2 = new char[11];
    strcpy(pch2, "1234567890");
    cout << &pch2 << " " << pch2 << endl;
    f(pch2);

    return 0;
}
```

gives next output:

```
0xbfa0d62c 1234567890 
0xbfa0d62c 1234567890
```

but if i would modify first row as follows

```
void f(char const * const & pch) {
```

i will get:

```
0xbfec7df8 1234567890
0xbfec7dfc 1234567890
```

is difference in pointers appeared because of need to mark new memory cell as const or something else?

Comment: Compiler can make copy, but it doesn't have to. Probably in optimized build you won't see any copies, in fact function `f` would likely be inlined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pch2` is a `char*`, not a `char const*`.  You cannot bind a reference of type `char const*&` to a pointer of type `char*`, so the following would be ill-formed:

```
char* p(0);
char const*& r(p);
```

Similarly, if your function was declared as `void f(char const*& pch)`, you would not be able to call it with a `char*` argument because of the const-qualifier mismatch.

The reason that your example works is that a const reference can bind to a temporary, and the compiler can construct a temporary copy of your `char*` pointer, give that temporary the type `char const*`, and bind the reference `pch` to that temporary pointer.

Comment: Try it with VC2010 and you see no copies created.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the parameter is an exact match to the function's parameter, so it can be bound directly to the reference.

In the second case the types are different (slightly) so the compiler creates a temporary that is passed to the function.